# STL Display Output

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I'm not really sure what's wrong with my code. I have got an error stating "expected unqualified-id before '.' token at the Travel.display()

```
class Travel{
    vector <Business> lBusiness;
 public:
    void display();
    };
void Travel::display()
    {
            vector <Business>::iterator ptr;
            for(ptr=lBusiness.begin();ptr!=lBusiness.end();ptr++)
            {
                (*ptr).display();
            }
    }
int main{
        vector <Business*>addB;
        vector<Travel*>addA;
        int choice;
        cin>>choice;
         if(choice==1){
               Travel.display();
               }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you forgot the semi-colon after the class definition.

```
class Travel{
    vector <Business> lBusiness;
 public:
    void display();
}; // <---
```

Secondly, `Travel` is the name of your class. Since `display` is not a static method, you need to call it on an instance of the class:

```
 Travel travel;
 travel.display();
```

Comment: What about `Travel.display();` is `main`?